# ReactJS - How a property can be setted by an argument following a comma?

Tags: javascript, properties, callback, jsx, setstate

I work currently on a specific section ReactJS documentation - here the corresponding link :  in https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html or on codepen : https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010#0 .

There is something in the code which interrogate me : 
How is possible that a value be updated by an argument passed in a function following a coma. Here the example to be more understandable :

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

corresponding to :
```

which handle :

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }
```

How the temperature argument can handle the setting of temperature property, if someone can explain me it would be great.

Kind regard,
J.Doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }
```

is equivalent to this : (notice the `temperature` property)

```
 handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({
        scale: 'c', 
        temperature: temperature
    });
  }
```

Which is equivalent to this :

```
 handleCelsiusChange(newValue) {
    this.setState({
        scale: 'c', 
        temperature: newValue
    });
  }
```

The first syntax is the [new shorthand form](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) introduced in ES6

Comment: Okay it's about shorthand form...  I see better now, thank you El Aoutar Hamza